# This file must be edited with the 'visudo' command.?

Tags: sudoedit

Why it is recommended to edit `/etc/sudoers` file with the `visudo` command?
Here is a sample of the file:

```
## Sudoers allows particular users to run various commands as
## the root user, without needing the root password.
##
## Examples are provided at the bottom of the file for collections
## of related commands, which can then be delegated out to particular
## users or groups.
##
## This file must be edited with the 'visudo' command.
```

Are there any special reasons for it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because `visudo` checks the syntax and make sure it is valid configuration file; otherwise you may edit the file, make an error and sudo won't be useable anymore just because of your syntax error.

Comment: +1, got your point; I edited the file with vi command made the error purportedly saved the file. I was not able to open the file afterwards.

Comment: @Ankit - You are aware, you can reboot into single-user mode and fix up /etc/sudoers and then reboot, right?

Comment: Hmm. I was unable to get `visudo` to complain on OS X 10.7.5, even when entering outlandish syntax and saving. Feature disabled?

Comment: @drjimbob, i was not aware of this, thanks. But i kept a backup of the default for safety.

Answer (score 18):

In addition to the syntax checks previously mentioned, `visudo` also locks `/etc/sudoers` so that it can't be edited by two users simultaneously.  A concurrent attempt to edit will give

```
visudo: /etc/sudoers busy, try again later
```

Comment: +1, i encountered this situation yesterday but was not sure of what could have caused it. Thanks :)

Comment: The commands `vipw` and `vigr` also exist for the same reason.

Comment: nitpicking: It can't be edited by two users using `visudo` (or `vipw` or `vigr` for `/etc/passwd`/`/etc/shadow` and `/etc/group`/`/etc/gshadow`), but it does not prevent another user to edit the file directly using any editor, as file locking in linux is just advisory.

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós: File locking may be advisory, but the files do not have the write bit set, and that is not advisory.

Comment: @DietrichEpp the `sudoers` file does not have write permission, but that won't prevent an unknowledgeable user to force-write it if he/she doesn't know about `sudo`

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós: If you have such a reckless user on your system with sudo access, all hope is lost.

Answer (score 8):

The reason for this is that `visudo` will verify the file does not have syntax errors prior to overwriting the current sudoers. This prevents you from accidently locking yourself out of root.