# How to password-protect a script on Linux?

Tags: shell-script, permissions, security, access-control, authorization

How do you set a password to execute a command or script in Linux?

I need to avoid a script (in which user and password details are included) from being used/executed from unauthorized users. So is there any way to set password to execute a particular script.

Comment: I'm missing environmental information here. Would a script calling another script make it? Kinda Python compiled script for a bit of security by obscurity?

Comment: @uprego - bad idea. Use `sudo`, obscurity != security!

Comment: @slm - bad myth. Security by obscurity is a valid approach when being a trustable environment and or is just about preventing naïve users damage things. I said environmental information was missing.

Comment: @uprego - not a myth at all. People can do what they want so long as they understand the tradeoffs. In this scenario there is a perfectly good choice already provided by most modern Linux installations, `sudo`.

Answer (score 5):

[Sudo](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo) might be the way to go.

Have your script owner and executable by a specific user and don't allow access from other users, 700 permissions for example.

Second, edit your sudoers file using `visudo` and add a line as the following:

```
%your_group ALL=path_to_script/script
```

All the users that are capable of running the script have to be added to your_group.

So, whoever is not part of your_group won't be able to run the script.
The alternative can be for you to specific just the username.

```
username ALL=path_to_script/script
```

Comment: You typically shouldn't edit your `/etc/sudoers` file directly, use the tool `visudo` to do edits.

Comment: updated the answer with the tools for editing. thanks @slm

Comment: You should [only use `visudo`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67929/this-file-must-be-edited-with-the-visudo-command) to edit `/etc/sudoers`. `sudoedit` won't check the file's syntax.

Comment: guess I got lucky with sudoedit without breaking it, updated answer. thanks

Comment: The question as asked doesn't call for or benefit from sudo: to keep credentials away from certain users, all it takes is to not give them read permission on the file that contains the credentials.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that the password is only readable by authorized users. Don't store the password in the script, store it in a separate file that you read from the script. It's a lot easier to manage permissions this way. If you store credentials in the script, it's hard to be sure where they'll end up: they may be inadvertently copied around, they should be entered in version control, etc.

Separating the credentials from the script has a second and arguably more important benefit. It separates “permission to execute the script” from “permission to access the resource”, which is good, because you aren't really trying to prevent people from executing your script, you're trying to prevent people from accessing the resource. So set the permissions on the password file accordingly, and you'll be set.

The easy way to manage permissions is to create a group and put the users who are allowed to access the resource in that group. Let's call the group `seniors`, and say that users `alice` and `bob` are allowed to access the resource. Create a group called `seniors` (e.g. `addgroup seniors`), and add the users to the group (e.g. `adduser alice seniors; adduser bob seniors`). Make the password file owned by the group `seniors` and readable only by the group.

```
chgrp seniors password.txt
chmod u=rw,g=r,o= password.txt    # or chmod 640 password.txt for short
```

---

Maybe you want some users to be able to execute the script but not to have arbitrary access to the resource. You don't mention this in your question, but I'll explain how it can be done just in case.

Suppose that the users `charlie` and `dominique` must be able to execute that particular script, but not access the resource otherwise. Create a group called `juniors` and put these users into this group. (You don't actually need to create a group but it makes management easier.) Create a [sudo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) rule that allows users in the group `juniors` to obtain the permissions of the group `seniors`, but only to execute one specific program — the script that reads the password file. Run `visudo` to add this line to the `sudoers` file:

```
%juniors ALL = (:seniors) /path/to/script ""
```

The juniors can execute the script by calling `sudo -g seniors /path/to/script`. The script will then run with the additional privileges conferred by the group `seniors`. Nonetheless the user who called `sudo` will not be able to access the password file (unless the script is buggy and can be tricked to leak it).

Note again that sudo is only useful if you need some people to be able to access the resource without knowing the password. It won't do anything for you if all you want is to restrict access to the password to certain users, and not allow anyone else to access the resource.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to those that replied. The eventual answer I implemented is ...
I found elsewhere on this site a routine for comparing passwords with /etc/shadow.

Because I am using a graphical interface I use zenity to prompt for a password. The person on the RPi does not know their password because of autologin Once a password is entered it is converted to a hash using the salt from the user account and the generated hash and original hash compared. If they are the same then the terminal program is run.

If the zenity cancelbutton is pressed or an incorrect password entered then nothing happens.

In order to run the script, which needs permissions to grep the /etc/shadow file I have an entry in /etc/sudoers.d/myfile = UserA ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /opt/myFiles/startTerminal.sh

The script is:

```
    USERNAME=UserA
    PASSWD=$(zenity --forms --title=" " \
        --text="Enter Password" \
        --add-password="" )

    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
        export PASSWD
        ORIGPASS=`grep -w "$USERNAME" /etc/shadow | cut -d: -f2`
        export ALGO=`echo $ORIGPASS | cut -d'$' -f2`
        export SALT=`echo $ORIGPASS | cut -d'$' -f3`
        GENPASS=$(perl -le 'print crypt("$ENV{PASSWD}","\$$ENV{ALGO}\$$ENV{SALT}\$")')
        if [ "$GENPASS" == "$ORIGPASS" ]; then
            /usr/bin/lxterminal &
            exit 0
        fi
    fi
```